# Why does setInterval run at different speeds

Tags: javascript

Why does `window.setInterval` run at different speeds on different computers. Is this purely just *lag* or is is something else?

Shouldn't 30ms be 30ms on all computers?

Comment: Can you define 'different speeds'. How are you telling the difference between these speeds?

Comment: @bowersbros I am comparing speeds using a simple web page I wrote that moves a box in a canvas until it hits a certain point. The time the box takes to move is much faster on my PC than on my laptop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're forgetting that for some Javascript calls they use the event-loop, so although you say 30ms you're basically saying queue and fire the callback *after* 30ms has elapsed.

What this means is, if there's a lot in the queue taking time then that callback will basically take longer to get to.

Obviously, the speed at which the event loop is processed is highly variable.

There's a nice article here explaining it in-depth - http://javascript.info/tutorial/events-and-timing-depth